# How to log the transactionid (Hibernate 3.3.1, Oracle)?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, transactions

Is it possible to log the low-level transactionid (I'm debugging something and this would be helpful to have in the log)?

The method to get that value is http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/transaction/xa/Xid.html#getGlobalTransactionId%28%29 but am not sure how to get the appropriate implementation (the javadoc points to an interface).

I've tried enabling TRACE logging for org.hibernate but no luck.

Thanks for any ideas.

EDIT: forgot to mention: running inside JBoss 5.1

Comment: I would just try to suggest to turn on 'log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=debug' if you havent tried already

Comment: I did (see the question, I had TRACE for the entire org.hibernate package, but the XID is not shown).